# Rails 4 Controller/Model associations and whitelisting attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Client model with the following line:

```
has_many :payments
```

and a Payments model with:

```
belongs_to :client
```

and

```
def generate_sepa

    sdd = SEPA::DirectDebit.new(
     name: 'name',
     bic: 'bic',
     iban: 'iban',
     creditor_identifier: 'identifier'
     )      

    SDD.add_transaction(
      name: @client.company,
      bic: @client.bic,
      iban: @client.iban,
      amount: self.amount,
      reference: self.payment_reference,
      remittance_information: self.remittance_information,
      mandate_id: self.mandate_id,
      mandate_date_of_signature: self.mandate_date_of_signature,
      local_instrument: 'CORE',
      sequence_type: self.sequence_type,
      requested_date: self.date_of_payment,
      batch_booking: self.batch_booking,)   

      sdd.to_xml    
end
```

In payments show view I have

```
<%= @payment.generate_sepa %>
```

and in payments controller

```
  def show
    @client = Client.find(:id => params[:client_id])
  end
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

> Unknown key: id

for

```
@client = Client.find(:id => params[:client_id])
```

In clients controller I also have:

```
def client_params
      params.require(:client).permit(:id, :trading_name, :company_name, :owner, :main_contact_name,
        :email, :phone, :date_joined, :trading_street_one, :trading_street_two, :trading_town, :trading_county, :iban, :bic)
end
```

and in payments:

```
def payment_params
  params.require(:payment).permit(:client_id, :signup_fee, :monthly_fee, :date_of_payment, :payment_reference,
    :remittance_information, :mandate_id, :mandate_date_of_signature, :batch_booking, :sequence_type, :is_recurring, :is_onceoff)
end
```

Is there an issue with the way I've whitelisted id? Or is there something wrong with the association between client and payments because, to be honest, I'm having a tough time figuring out what's going wrong.

EDIT

:client_id gets passed to payments like so when I create a new client:

```
  def create
    @client = Client.new(client_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @client.save
        format.html { redirect_to new_payment_url(:client_id => @client.id) }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @client }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @client.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

in the payments _form partial I also have:

```
<%= f.hidden_field('client_id', :value => params[:client_id]) %>
```

along with the rest of the form fields.

Comment: Could you post your relevant view templates?

Comment: can you try `Client.find(params[:id])`

Comment: tkymtk It's up there. In my view all I really have is <%= @payment.generate_sepa %> and links for 'edit' and 'back'

Comment: @Thaha that's passing in the payment id to clients instead of the proper client_id so it doesn't work.

Comment: how you are passing the client id?. Like this? `client_path(@payment.id,client_id: @client.id)`. Or can you share that show url?

Comment: @Thahakp I've added the code you requested. Hope it's what you were looking for.

Comment: `Payment.find(params[:id]).client` not working in payment show?

Comment: @Thahakp I'm having difficulty reading that line of code. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Assuming that you are calling payments/show after creating new payment for a particular client(redirec_to payment_path(@payment)). You can get the client object with the payment like this `@payment= Payment.find(params[:id]); @client = @payment.client`

Comment: If you are still not getting, please ahow me the payment create method. You can remove client create from question , it is not needed

Comment: @Thahakp thanks so much! I have a couple of other problems to work through but I think that solved the issue of fetching the correct client. If you want to post your solution as an answer, I'll gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In payment controller/show `@client = Client.find(params[:id])` will not work.

Use

```
@payment= Payment.find(params[:id])
@client = @payment.client
```

Because you are passing payment id to the show, not the client id.

Answer (score 0):

```
def show
  @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
end
```

Isn't it?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the syntax looks better but I'm getting 'couldn't find client without an id'. Logs have the same message.